# Не правильно работает JavaScript в WebView Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

1. Нужно заполнить форму на сайте, используя JavaScript.
2. Запустить скрипт для заполнения форм на сайте. Но такой метод не работает. Результат на скриншоте: Висит текст, который я хотел закинуть в форму. Если использовать этот метод JavaScript в Google Chrome с компа - всё окей, заполняет что нужно.

---

КОРОТКО: Нужно управлять страницей WebView с Android используя JavaScript: заполнять формы, нажимать кнопки. Многие методы работают на пк, но не на андрюше... API на сайте нету, да и сайт не мой, но нужно запилить приложение для обработки данных, которые можно взять только после авторизации.

---

[image: Скриншот, когда запускаю первый скрипт на телефоне]

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://dekanat.kneu.edu.ua/cgi-bin/classman.cgi?n=2");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById(\"user_name\").value = \"TEST\";");
        }
    });
```

3. Если загружаю этот скрипт:

   mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: alert(\"TEST\");");

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `javascript:document.getElementById('user_name').setAttribute('value', 'TEST');` - такой скрипт попробуйте. Пройти авторизацию можно без WebView, если она Вам нужна только для этого. Отправляем пост-запросом данные формы и при успешной авторизации сохраняем куки. Потом с этими куками мы можем получать нужные страницы, парсить их и показывать любым удобным способом.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо огромное! Заработало)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установка свойств присвоением не всегда работает как хотелось, но можно это сделать и методом `element.setAttribute(attributename, attributevalue)`:

```
    document.getElementById('user_name').setAttribute('value', 'TEST');
```